# RestSharp content response returning bad json format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I am using RestSharp library to make requests to an WebApi.
This is how i am doing it:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", autentication);
RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This works good until here. The issue that i have is that the content of the response is returning like this:

```
string jsonObject2 = "\"{\\\"status\\\":\\\"success\\\",\\\"entities\\\":[{\\\"bank_code\\\":2,\\\"name\\\":\\\"BANK 02\\\"},{\\\"bank_code\\\":3,\\\"name\\\":\\\"BANCK 03\\\"},{\\\"bank_code\\\":4,\\\"name\\\":\\\"BANCK 04\\\"}]}\"";
```

The response.content is adding 2 more \ and when i tried to deserialize and it throws an exception that it cannot convert a string to my model.

How can i resolve that the content returns in this format?

```
 string jsonObject = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"entities\":[{\"bank_code\":2,\"name\":\"BANK 02\"},{\"bank_code\":3,\"name\":\"BANK 03\"},{\"bank_code\":4,\"name\":\"BANK 04\"}]}";
```

This format i can deserialize because of the correct string json format.

Comment: It seems your API is not returning JSON, but rather an escaped string. Is the API your own?

Comment: The API is an existing project and when i test in POSTMAN is working properly.

Comment: By properly, you mean that you receive `"{\"status\":\"success\",\"entities\":[{\"bank_code\":2,\"name\":\"BANK 02\"},{\"bank_code\":3,\"name\":\"BANK 03\"},{\"bank_code\":4,\"name\":\"BANK 04\"}]}"`? Because that is not JSON and won't deserialize correctly.

Comment: But is working when deserializing using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Only don't work when the content has two more slashes in the string like this "\\\"

Comment: Please try using  "return Content(result, "application/json");"  has your return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when i deserialize to string the content that returns the API and then deserialize again the string into the model type that i want.

```
 string jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(restResponse.Content);
 EntidadResponse data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntidadResponse>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Empty;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                        {
                            result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        }
return Content(result, "application/json");
```